# Grails 3.3.11 Integration Tests - Rollback transactions

Tags: grails

I am in doubt with my grails 3.3.11 integration tests. I thought that, by default, grails would not persist my test data in the database. But, I don't know why, all tests I do are being saved in the database.

Is there a way to rollback all transactions after performing all the test cases?

Thanks,

Alfredo

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Rollback` annotation

https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting

> The Rollback annotation ensures that each test method runs in a transaction that is rolled back. Generally this is desirable because you do not want your tests depending on order or application state.
>
> In Grails 3.0 tests rely on grails.gorm.transactions.Rollback annotation to bind the session in integration tests. Though each test method transaction is rolled back, the setup() method uses a separate transaction that is not rolled back.

Comment: This appears to be a question, not an answer.